# wxPython - run function after GUI is fully drawn

Tags: wxpython

What would be the standard way to do this?

I don't want there to be a delay when opening the program, but I want my function to run as soon as GUI has been drawn.

I've tried `wx.CallAfter(foo.bar)`, the Window (`Frame`) opens immediately, but the buttons don't get drawn until my function has executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wx.FutureCall(0, foo.bar)
```

This puts an event into the event queue that will call the function after 0 milliseconds.

This causes the function to be run as soon as GUI has been drawn.